# custom field ordering in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am facing strange issue with custom field in django admin, Here I am trying ordering the field using django model manager.

```
class PracticeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, ):
        qs = super(PracticeManager, self).get_query_set().all()
        # qs = sorted(qs, key=operator.attrgetter('id'))
        print qs
        return qs

class Practice(models.Model):
    """docstring for Practice"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Name')
    ip = models.IPAddressField(verbose_name="Ip Address")
    objects = PracticeManager()

    def number_of_orders(self):
        return u'%s' % self
    number_of_orders.admin_order_field = 'ip'
```

admin.py:

```
class PracticeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('number_of_orders', 'name')
```

The above code works fine and prints the list of objects in the terminal and also django admin dashboard working perfectly,

```
[<Practice: 10.90.90.1>, <Practice: 10.90.90.13>, <Practice: 9.5.3.2>, <Practice: 10.90.90.11>]
```

But when I enable the below line,

```
qs = sorted(qs, key=operator.attrgetter('id'))
```

It throws strange error on the admin dashboard panel,

```
Database error
Something's wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user.
```

But the object list prints on the terminal. Why I am facing this problem ?

Comment: Bad practice to return list instead of queryset. After you call `sorted` function, `qs` is not queryset anymore. The error you get is strange. Anyway, your code should not work as you expect because django admin tries to apply `filter` function to return value it gets from `models.Manager.get_query_set()`. What kind of sorting are you trying to do? Why don't you use `qs = qs.order_by('id')` instead of that commented line?

Comment: Thanks for instant reply, Yes I am doing stupid thing. But I really want this `sorted(qs, key=key=lambda item: socket.inet_aton(item))`, Is it possible ?

Comment: even if you could do this, it would be really abnormal solution.

Comment: However, if this ordering is really important, you can create additional column and store there ip in 32-bit format integer. Then just bind signals on `post_save` of your model to dinamically fill that field later. Solution is stupid. But if you really need it should help.

Answer (score 1):

By using `sorted`, you're converting the queryset to a list. But `get_query_set` must return a queryset, hence the name: anything that operates on the values returned from that manager will be expecting a QS.

There's no good reason to do that sort in Python. You should add it to the ORM call:

```
qs = super(PracticeManager, self).get_query_set().order_by('id')
```

or even better, set the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#ordering) attribute in the model's Meta class.

Comment: Thanks for instant reply, Yes I am doing stupid thing. But I really want this `sorted(qs, key=key=lambda item: socket.inet_aton(item))`, Is it possible ?